# How do I set bash aliases and variables from within vim?

Tags: bash, vim, alias, vi, variable

In cmdline mode, the following examples do not work for me.

```
!alias lol='echo lol'
!lol='echo lol'
```

Comment: Possible cross site duplicate of: http://superuser.com/questions/47821/vim-ignores-aliases

Answer (score 6, accepted):

When you use the `:!` command, a new shell is spawned from within Vim. In that shell, the alias is set, but immediately after that, the shell exits, and all is lost.

Best define the aliases in the shell that starts Vim. For environment variables, you can also set them from within Vim via `:let $VAR = 'value'`, and you can use those in `:!` commands. And you can start a shell from within Vim with `:shell`, or suspend Vim and go back to the original shell with `:stop` or `^z`.

Answer (score 4):

`vim` starts one instance of a non-interactive `bash` (assuming `bash` is your login shell and you haven't modified `$SHELL`) for each `!` command (in `!cmd`, vim runs `bash -c cmd`). So:

1. An alias defined in one ! command, would not be available in the other shell started by the next ! command since it's a different process altogether.
2. `bash` doesn't expand aliases and doesn't read `~/.bashrc` when not interactive

To work around that, you could set `$BASH_ENV` to something that enables alias expansion and rewrites itself on exit of `bash` with the list of new aliases included. Something like (in `~/.vimrc`):

```
let $BASH_ENV = $HOME . "/.bashvimrc." . getpid()
au VimLeave * silent !exec rm -f "$BASH_ENV"
silent !echo 'vim_setup() { shopt -s expand_aliases; trap write_aliases EXIT; eval "$@"; }; write_aliases() { typeset -f vim_setup write_aliases; alias; echo vim_setup \"\$@\";} > "$BASH_ENV"; vim_setup "$@"' > "$BASH_ENV"
set shell=/bin/bash
```

Comment: Thank you a lot for your detailed answer, but that's a bit too much ~/.vimrc trickery for my taste. I prefer the "use :let or drop out of vim and define them in the shell" solution from Ingo Karkat.